# Compile .jsx files instead of .js using babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm starting to learn `ReactJs`, and I was trying to build an environment from scratch using [this "builder"](https://web.archive.org/web/20171025193258/https://www.andrewhfarmer.com/build-your-own-starter/#0-intro).

Everything works pretty well, but I'd like to work with `.jsx` files instead of `.js` (the text editor screws up otherwise, and ir feels better using a different extension for not-compiled scripts)

However, I didn't manage to compile such `.jsx` files, it only works with `.js` files.

This is the configuration files for `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets":["es2015","react"]
}
```

And my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

var config = {
    context: path.join(__dirname,'src'),
    entry:[
        './main.js'
    ],
    output:{
        path    :path.join(__dirname,'www'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                loaders:['babel']
            }
        ],
    },
    resolveLoader:{
        root: [
            path.join(__dirname,'node_modules')
        ]
    },
    resolve:{
        root:[
            path.join(__dirname,'node_modules')
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I tried simply changing the extensions in the webpack config file from `js` to `jsx`, but to no avail.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just replace this line:

```
test: /\.js$/,
```

with:

```
test: /\.jsx$/,
```

It will run babel loader on the `.jsx` files, **instead of** `.js` files.

If you want to transpile **both** `.js` and `.jsx`, you can set it to `/\.jsx?$/`, where `?` in regex indicates to match 0 or 1 occurrences of the preceding character: test positive for both `.js` and `.jsx`.

`.test` property indicates a condition that must be met to run the loader specified in the `loader` key. You can read more about `module.loader` options [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders).

Also, when importing modules, you should add the `.jsx` extension, like this:

```
import Counter from './Counter.jsx';
```

Or set webpack's [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions) config to add `.jsx` extension (by default, it looks only for .js files). Like this:

```
resolve: {
   /* ... */
   extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
 }
```

This way, you can import your files without the extension:

```
import Counter from './Counter';
```

Comment: changed the lines you pointed out, but still, it throws an error when I start the server: `ERROR in ./src/main.jsx: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./Counter` both js files (main and counter) are .jsx files.

Comment: @Sebastianb I edited with a new information. Can you try again?

Comment: This is very useful, thanks. Particularly, the part about resolving extensions and editing webpack config to automatically resolve .jsx files.