# Module parse failed: es6 react component with JSX inside .JS file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx, babel-loader

Webpack Babel loader fails when importing an es6 react component with .js as the filename extension. If the filename extension is changed to .jsx babel compiles properly. Any clue?

```js
var config = {
  entry : {
    "login" : PAGE_DIR + '/login/index.js',
    "app" : PAGE_DIR + '/app/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
  rules : [
     {
        test : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include : PAGE_DIR,
    exclude: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
    ],
        loaders : ['babel-loader']
      }
  ]
  }
};
```

EDIT:

Updating the logs below.

```js
> webpack -d

Hash: 83d5fd2d0c1113e55b32
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 2057ms
          Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  app-bundle.js  2.28 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
login-bundle.js  1.98 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  login
  [18] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js 6.21 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [19] ./~/react/lib/React.js 2.69 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [31] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [80] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [109] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js 5.14 kB {0} {1} [built]
 [179] ./~/redux/es/index.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
 [192] ./app/state/store.js 330 bytes {0} [built]
 [193] ./~/react-redux/es/index.js 194 bytes {0} [built]
 [196] ./app/state/reducer.js 766 bytes {0} [built]
 [209] ./~/react-redux/es/connect/connect.js 5.34 kB {0} [built]
 [215] ./~/react-redux/es/utils/Subscription.js 2.59 kB {0} [built]
 [216] ./~/react-redux/es/utils/shallowEqual.js 677 bytes {0} [built]
 [220] ./~/redux-logger/lib/index.js 4.45 kB {0} [built]
 [228] ./app/pages/app/index.jsx 694 bytes {0} [built]
 [229] ./app/pages/login/index.jsx 2.33 kB {1} [built]
    + 215 hidden modules

ERROR in ./app/components/login.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/vsank1/Documents/workspace/registration/kudumbayogam/app/components/login.jsx Unexpected token (15:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render () {
|     return (
|       <form className="login">
|         <input type="email" name="emailid" placeholder="Email ID" onChange={this.changeEmailId.bind(this)} /><br/>
|         <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.changePassword.bind(this)} /><br/>
 @ ./app/pages/login/index.jsx 11:13-50

ERROR in ./app/components/app.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/vsank1/Documents/workspace/registration/kudumbayogam/app/components/app.jsx Unexpected token (30:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|     return (
|    <div className='row'>
|     <div className='twelve columns'>
|      <a href='#logout' className='logout button-link'>Logout</a>
 @ ./app/pages/app/index.jsx 15:11-46
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile .jsx files instead of .js using babel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815333/compile-jsx-files-instead-of-js-using-babel), this ques is answered very well there check the link.

Comment: @Mayank No, I get a compile error when I use .js file. If I rename it to .jsx and pass it as the entry it compiles properly. Thanks

Comment: did you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41815369/5185595 ??  you need to do the changes in `webpack.config.js` to allow both extensions.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. I am passing this `/\.(js|jsx)$/` regex for testing the filename pattern. So, the loader should handle the both .js & .jsx.

Comment: tried that. doesnt solve it. ERROR - `Module parse failed:` `Unexpected Token` `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: found `/\.(js|jsx)$/` from here - https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/198 . Still throws the error though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139355/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-vishnu-sankaran).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I had made a mistake by adding an include folder. My components resided outside the **include** folder and all these components were not getting parsed with the loader. What I found is webpack only parse files which matches the **test** pattern and is also inside the include folder.

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/assets/js');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/');

var config = {
  entry : {
    "login" : APP_DIR + '/pages/login/index.js',
    "app" : APP_DIR + '/pages/app/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: ohh this was the mistake, explanation makes sense :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install configure presets in you webpack config like

```
module : {
        rules : [
           {
            test : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include : PAGE_DIR,
            exclude: [
                  path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            ],
            loaders : ['babel-loader'],
            query: {
                 presets: ['react','es2015', 'stage-0']
             }
            }
        ]
  }
```

Install them first using

```
npm install -S babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0
```

Comment: I have `{ "presets" : ["es2015", "react"] }` in my `.babelrc` file. what is `stage-0` for?

Comment: I have installed and added `stage-0` also the preset list. Still the same result. Thanks,